# What's the best way to germinate blackberry seeds?

Tags: seeds, germination, blackberry

I ate some blackberries (last June) and kept some seeds. I tried two ways to germinate some.

- First way, I used an empty white plastic jar where I put some water and seeds. I put the jar in a dark place (in my closet).
- Second way, I used an empty transparent plastic cookies box, where I put some seeds between some wet paper towels. I put the box in my fridge.

During the last two months I checked every two weeks to look for some difference. The only difference I was able to see was the decay of the seeds in the box in the fridge.

I really would like to understand how I can germinate these seeds, so later on I can expect to see them growing and making fruits!

I don't know if it's pertinent or not, so I added the picture of the rest of the seeds.

[image]

Comment: Is your interest primarily in getting good fruit? Or are you just seeing if you can get them to grow?

Comment: @GardenerJ Hi, I want first to make them grow. Anyway, why are you asking ?

Comment: Because for good fruit it would likely be easier, quicker and more reliable to buy a grown plant.

Comment: @GardenerJ yes, but this is not really the most important for me. I want to make growing things from seeds. Anyway, thx for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blackberry seeds need to be scarified and stratified in order to germinate. Furthermore, it seems that drying the seeds first may induce dormancy inhibiting germination.  So, maybe you went wrong in one of the above procedures?

http://hortsci.ashspublications.org/content/30/1/124.full.pdf

Comment: I was thinking about that, actually I still have those seeds. I thought to put them during one month outside of my place, I heard the freeze can do the job. I will print your publi and read it carefully. thx for that paper.

Comment: I suspect your seeds have dried and can not be germinated now. But give it a go. And please accept my answer :)

Comment: I never accept an answer without reading the link/paper inside. I read it yesterday. Was interesting, now you deserve your +10